# Неверный вывод ответа

Tags: c++

**Суть:**

1. Вводим количество чисел
2. Вводим числа. Считаем, сколько есть в массиве каждого числа.
   Например, для mass = {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2};

Вводя 3 числа: 4, 2, 3  Получим: 1, 3, 2

Сама программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int m, n, u; int mykey;
    cin >> n;  // количество чисел 
    int mass[n] = { 0 };
    int r = n - 1; int l = 0; int mid = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    sort(mass, mass + n);
    cin >> m; // количество чисел для поиска
    int perr[m] = { 0 }; int chislo[m] = { 0 };
    for (int g = 0; g < m; g++) {
        cin >> perr[g];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (perr[g] == mass[i]) chislo[mid] = chislo[mid] + 1;
            else i++;
            mid = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) 
    cout << chislo[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод данной программы - одни нули. В чем проблема и как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

А нельзя проще - использовать, например, `map`?

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    map<int,int> m;
    for(int i = 0, j; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> j;
        m[j]++;
    }
    for(auto x: m)
        cout << "число " << x.first << " повторяется " << x.second << " раз\n";
```

Просто продраться через ваш код и понять, что он делает, лично я не в состоянии...

Comment: Можно, но это лишь часть от требуемой.

Comment: Ну что, вы не в состоянии запросить число k и вывести значение m[k]? Неужели надо разжевывать до такой степени, чтоб вам оставалось только сдать и получить оценку? Не трудясь совсем?